# how to add a portal role by python code

Tags: plone, roles

I'm on plone 4.1 and I need to create a portal role by code and I cannot find any official reference.

After a bit of grepping I found this:

```
acl_users.portal_role_manager.addRole
```

Which seems to create the role but the role afaict is not available anywhere, nor in the security tab nor in the roles listed on /@@usergroup-userprefs.

Then I found also an "_addRole" on the portal object (which I think comes from eggs/Zope2-2.13.8-py2.6.egg/OFS/role.py).

I found a use of this in http://repositorio.interlegis.gov.br/ILSAAP/trunk/InstallUtils/installers/installRoles.py

and I'm now using

```
portal._addRole(new_role)
try:
    acl_users.portal_role_manager.addRole(new_role)
except:
    pass
```

that works! :)

The use real use-case is a specific blueprint for transmogrifier:

https://github.com/simahawk/collective.blueprint.usersandgroups/blob/master/collective/blueprint/usersandgroups/blueprint.py#L62

The question is: is this the way to go?

Comment: the naked except clause looks hoaky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roles are store localy in each zodb object so you can modify like that

```
## Roles are store on __ac_roles__ attribute of object.
roles = list(portal.__ac_roles__)
roles += 'yournewrole'
portal.__ac_roles__ = tuple(roles)
```

I think it's enough for your use case.

Comment: yes, I found that too, but I didn't know if it was the right thing to do. It seems more an hack than a proper API :)

Comment: Ok ! The real API is defined in OFS.role as you say and according http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zdgbook/Security.html . After, if you want that your role can be manage in plone management interface (prefs_...) you must add on portal_role_manager plugin . Why ? because you don't want manage all roles in PMI interface (per example manager) or you have develop a plugin that provide dynamic specific role on context that are not store on zodb and you want to manage it also (ILocalRolesPlugin or IRolesPlugin)

Comment: I see, thanks for and answer and above all for the comment :)